# Change Tab text size

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

In MainActivity, I have implemented ActionBar with TabListener and Viewpager.

I need to **change the selected Tab's text size** to a bit bigger size.

This is how onCreate() method looks like, with these implementations.

```
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    vpAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(vpAdapter);

    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }
    });

    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        }
    };

    Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
            .setText(getString(R.string.basic_setup))
            .setTabListener(tabListener);
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    tab = actionBar.newTab()
            .setText(getString(R.string.location))
            .setTabListener(tabListener);
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    tab = actionBar.newTab()
            .setText(getString(R.string.advanced_setup))
            .setTabListener(tabListener);
    actionBar.addTab(tab);
```

My idea is that I should be able to modify this in ActionBar.TabListener's onTabSelected() method, but I don't know how could I do it.